# UITableViewCell background disappears?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

The UITableViewController in my app pulls data from a json data source. I have also created a custom UITableViewCell background using CG. There is a very interesting bug that happens and I have no idea why. I will walk you through what happens and how I recreate it:

Tap to enter table view. 
Without scrolling the table at all I immediately tap on an item in view. 
After tapping on that item I press the back button to return to the table view. 
If I then scroll down the first cell to appear from off screen will not have my custom back ground. It will just be the default for a cell. Then if I continue to scroll down every 10th cell will have the same issue.

This bug only occurs in this exact process. If I were to scroll the table view at all before tapping on an item it would not happen.

Here is the relevant code for the tableview controller:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Will remove all of the used codes from the table if setting is enabled
    if (self.shouldHideCodes) {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [self.jsonCodeData mutableCopy];
        [tempArray removeObjectsInArray:[self.usedCodes usedCodes]];
        self.jsonCodeData = tempArray;
    }

    return [self.jsonCodeData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (self.jsonCodeData) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"code cell"];

        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CodeCellTVC class]]) {
            CodeCellTVC *tvcCell = (CodeCellTVC *)cell;

            if (![tvcCell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
                tvcCell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
            }

            NSDictionary *codeDict = [self.jsonCodeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            // Retrieve code string from dictionary
            NSString *codeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [codeDict objectForKey:@"code"]];

            tvcCell.codeTableLabel.text = codeText;

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The thing that confuses me is how it reacts. That when the bug happens every 10th cell has the issue and not every one. I don't have anything outside of these method's that deal with the tableviewcell itself.

Comment: Do your if statements guarantee that they are always true? Because if not, then you can run into reusability issues.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem, you did a wrong at the time of initializing the cell,Every time your intializing the cell, so that every time memory will allocate for that cell, it will create memory issue.
Edit the code like bellow it will work for you.

```
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"code cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"code cell"];
    }
```

Comment: hello @Jain, Please tell me

Comment: Please add me @mrsamkitjain@gmail.com..lets chat there